# Classic ASP page not rendering properly ( partially rendering ) on n Windows Server 2012 R2 ( IIS 8.5 )

Tags: windows, iis, server, asp-classic

I have an old application developed using classic ASP, it was running fine under Windows Server 2008 and IIS 7.0. We recently upgrade to Windows Server 2012 R2, since that the application is not running fine:

I have application of Classic ASP and running on Windows Server 2012 R2 ( IIS 8.5 ). But recently asp page is not rendering fully, It is just rendering partially.

I have tried below solution.

1. Delete .Net temporary files for .net version 2 & 4 (Also for 32bit & 64bit),  Directories are given below.

```
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
    C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\Temporary ASP.NET Files\
```

2. Go to the IIS Settings => Pages and Controls
   Change Client Mode => Static and click on `Apply at Right side top in Action Menu`
3. Now reboot the server.
4. Check again if the page is render properly or not.
   4.1 If the page is render properly, Change the Client Mode => Predictable.
   4.2 restart the iis by iisreset
5. If still there is an issue, again delete the .net temp files.
   5.1  restart the iis by iisreset (Reboot server again if its require)
   5.2 Check the requests, It should render properly.
   5.2 Again go to IIS Settings => Pages and Controls.
6. Change Client Mode => Predictable (`Don't forget to click on Apply`)
7. Again iisreset from a command prompt.
8. Check the same page again page must render on every requests.

After applying above steps, Page is working fine. But after some times, Issue is started to occurring.

Any help would be appreciated . Thanks in advance.

Comment: when you say rendering partially, do you mean it is just stopping halfway so the HTML just stops? Screenshot of the source? Is it consistent? If you refresh does it always stop at the same place?

Comment: Yes. It just stop halfway or some time 75% page renders...etc. If I refresh , It does not  always stop at the same place.

Comment: did you install the asp feature of the iis [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wh9vG.png)? Create a file called Hello.asp in the content folder for IIS, use this code:
`<%
   strWrld="Hello World"
%>

<HTML>
<TITLE>ASP Test Page</TITLE>`

If you see "Hello World", then ASP pages in this Web application are serving properly. did you get an error message? and what kind of content you are trying to display? also, browse the site and press f12 and check the console. which pipeline mode you are using? you also don't need to change the Client Mode.what is the size of the webpage?

Comment: Have you check the page source to see if an error is being generated? I've had instances in the past where a hefty page has caused a timeout in the middle of a table row which wouldn't show up on the render because the page wouldn't contain a fully rendered table before the error occurred.

Comment: Also if you are dealing with a Classic ASP Web Application, clearing the ASP.Net temporary file cache will have no effect as that is specific to ASP.Net Web Applications and has nothing to do with Classic ASP.